# MongoDB. Set unique number to each document in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some issue about unique values in collection. Does someone know which operator or condition should i use in order to set uniq number to each document in mongo with method updateMany?

For example:

```
{title: 'Hello'}, 
{title: 'World'},
{title: 'Mongo'},
{title: 'JSON'}
```

I need to append `place` field in loop with value +1:

```
{title: 'Hello', place: 1}, 
{title: 'World', place: 2},
{title: 'Mongo', place: 3},
{title: 'JSON', place: 4}
```

Comment: what is your collection size(total no.of docs) ?

Comment: It is not so big. But i know how to do it in loop take some document with offset and save with new field but i interested in how to do it in one row with one request?

Answer (score 1):

**Experimentally** (depending on the size of your collection) you can try to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#document-operand-with-options) which takes an `includeArrayIndex` parameter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$docs",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$docs", { place: "$index" } ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R82J5njy5Ag)

You can also consider [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to replace existing collection with above aggregation result