# Mongo $addField - add the index of the current result set as field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i want to add a field that contains the index inside a result set but i cant find a proper expression to do so.

```
aggregate([
  { $match: { } },
  { $addFields: { order: { ??? } },
  { ... }
])
```

For example if i have a set of

```
[
  { a: 'b' },
  { a: 'c' },
  { a: 'd' },
]
```

i want to get

```
[
  { a: 'b', order: 0 },
  { a: 'c', order: 1 },
  { a: 'd', order: 2 },
]
```

i cant just add it on the client side as i limit and offset the result further down the aggregation chain and i don't know the exact offset so the final result might look something like

```
[
 { a: 'd', order: 2 },
]
```

Is there a valid expression that i can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093759/mongodb-set-unique-number-to-each-document-in-collection/61112607#61112607 ?

Comment: interesting... although this seems very expensive for sth so simple. I will play around with it, see how it behaves. Thanks!